# can't get the name of Dbpedia classes

Tags: java, owl, dbpedia, owl-api

While I'm trying to get classes of Dbpedia ontology using the code below

```
    public void classofontology(){      

   Set<OWLClass> classes =  ontology.getClassesInSignature();
   System.out.println("le nombre des classes total de l'ontologie est : "+classes.size());          
   for(OWLClass clss: classes) 
    System.out.println(clss.getIRI().getFragment());

           }
```

I get the total number of classes, So they're all browsed but I can't have the name of classes: I get as output "null" but when I try by using directly `clss` instead of `clss.getIRI().getFragment()` I get the IRI . I need just the name of the classes and I can't understand why I can't get it, I would be grateful
If you can help me to get it. Thank you

Ps: I notice that classes don't have all the same IRI as you can see for Building and Book classes, Can this be the source of the problem ?

Building IRI gotten by the code 
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Building

Book IRI gotten by the code 
http://schema.org/Book

Comment: 1. As usual, read the [Java doc] (http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/IRI.html#getFragment--) to get an explanation of what the method does return and why sometimes null. 2. Use the `SimpleIRIShortFormProvider`  if you really want to get the name from the IRI. 3. Why don't you use the `rdfs:label` instead? That's best-practice as labels are supposed to provide the "real" human-readable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, IRIs do not have names.

The last part of an `IRI` (from the last slash or hash character, or digit) is returned by the `getFragment()` method; however, there is no guarantee that a valid `IRI` has such a fragment (the `IRI` might be terminated with a hash or a dash, or it might have only numbers after the last value). The reason behind this is that the fragment must be an XML QName - it is used in RDF/XML for naming tags.

For example, `IRI.create("http://www.example.com/test/1234").getFragment()` will return an empty string.

As suggested by [AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/aksw), use either a `SimpleIRIShortFormProvider` or, if your entities have labels, an `AnnotationValueShortFormProvider`.

Comment: Thank you Ignazio and @AKSW

Comment: @Ignazio One question from my side: what does `IRI::getShortForm` return? Javadoc says indeed the "short form", but what exactly does this mean?

Comment: `getShortForm()` checks the following: "does the IRI have a fragment? if so, that's the short form", then "does the IRI have a / character not at the end? Then that's the short form (i.e., http://sometest.com/test#1234 ->test#1234)". Else the quoted form is returned: `<http://sometest.com/test/>`